# symfony deploy permission error

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing first deploy on my server, but I have problem with permisions.

I'm using jenkins for deploy my build step looks like this:

```
 echo '
  parameters:
     database_driver: pdo_mysql
     database_host: %database.host%
     database_port: null
     database_name: symfonyapp
     database_user: %database.user%
     database_password: %database.password%
     mailer_transport: smtp
     mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
     mailer_user: null
     mailer_password: null
     locale: cs
     secret: 08b6b8f6548a96bd1ff1533ec02e39ae
  '> app/config/parameters.yml

export SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER=user
export SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST=localhost
export SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD=secret

composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug

touch app/logs/prod.log
chmod -R 777 app/cache
chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

But I'm getting this error and don't know why because I set everything, also folder logs and cache are writable

```
[Fri Sep 06 12:09:24 2013] [error] [client 217.112.169.14] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 315
[Fri Sep 06 12:09:24 2013] [error] [client 217.112.169.14] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/anotherPath/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php:4787\nStack trace:\n
#0 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4735): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n
#1 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4664): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n
#2 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4850): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array)\n
#3 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5066): Monolog\\Handler\\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array)\n
#4 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5166): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)\n
#5 /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 4787
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd line in trace is telling you what's wrong.

```
[Fri Sep 06 12:09:24 2013] [error] [client 217.112.169.14] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/anotherPath/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /projectPath/app/cache/prod/classes.php:4787\nStack trace:\n
```

And for jenkins it's much better to use [phing](http://www.phing.info/) or ant. Check out http://jenkins-php.org/ for handy setup.

Just as an idea. I guess your bash script is not being executed in a proper working directory. You can check this just `ls -lah app/logs/prod.log`

If you have paths other than on server where you invoke cache:clear then you will have wrong path in cache/prod/classes.php. You need to make same path for all servers that use rsync.

Comment: But that file exist, I did create it inside build step with touch.

Comment: I known what is wrong, I'm building everything on another server. And is sync with Rsync to another so there is another path from build server.

Comment: well I need to make some reconfiguration on server since user which is owner on production server don't have bash. Best would be have same paths on both servers but that is not possible now.